# How to listen to requests made on an open port

Tags: linux, osx, kali-linux, port-forwarding, chromecast

I am trying to make a `masterQueue` for Chromecast. It will enable inter-app queuing. I am stuck with few network basics. I am using an older cast sdk because it provided Java API.

It could be very vague and may not be appropriate for this site, but I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

What I have done so far :

- I have used this [code](https://github.com/vitalidze/chromecast-java-api-v2)
- I figured that my chrome cast runs on `10.0.0.x` and is open on port `8089`.

What can I possibly do to listen to all the cast requests made to `10.0.0.x:8089`. I want to store the request in the queue and keep polling and playing until my queue is empty.

I did the following commands to get more insights :

```
Aakashs-MacBook-Pro:~ aakashshah$ sudo lsof -n -P -i :8009
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google      614 aakashshah  149u  IPv4 0x3837229g56402e0d      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.xxx:64416->10.0.0.xx:8009 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      614 aakashshah  315u  IPv4 0x3837224598nnfe0d      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.xxx:64411->10.0.0.x:8009 (ESTABLISHED)
java      84205 aakashshah   22u  IPv6 0x3837229f49a79725      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.xxx:49562->10.0.0.x:8009 (ESTABLISHED)
java      84205 aakashshah   24u  IPv6 0x3837229f49a7a2a5      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.xxx:49563->10.0.0.x:8009 (ESTABLISHED)
```

In the above result `10.0.0.xxx` is my IP address. I want to continuously listen to this port and see what requests are made on chromecast.

I would also like to understand what does `10.0.0.xxx:64411->10.0.0.x:8009 (ESTABLISHED)` mean especially `10.0.0.xxx:64411->10.0.0.x:8009`. What does the port 64411 do? I am guessing is it a free port available on my router. So it used that to talk to chromecast.

Can I reverse proxy/ port forward/ reverse something to listen to *requests made on 8009* over some other free port?

I am trying to understand mDNS after landing on this [page](https://github.com/jloutsenhizer/CR-Cast/wiki/Chromecast-Implementation-Documentation-WIP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There's no need to obfuscate `10.0.0.x` addresses: These are private IP range addresses, and will never be visible publicly.

2) You can't "listen to all requests made to 10.0.0.x:8089": Chromecast will store those requests internally, and unless Chromecast has debugging code for this, there's no way to make it spit out those requests. But you can

2a) Use `wireshark` to sniff on all network traffic that is exchanged; the requests will be part of that

2b) Use a proxy that accepts requests on a different address, and forwards them. Then you can query the proxy. A very simple proxy can probably be implemented with `socat` as first approximation, but you can't query `socat`...

3) `TCP 10.0.0.y:64411->10.0.0.x:8009 (ESTABLISHED)` means that the host with IP address `10.0.0.y` has established a TCP connection (a reliable stateful method of communication via a byte stream) from port `64411` to port `8009` on host `10.0.0.x`; and one of those is your local machine.

4) From the questions you are asking, you will probably need some time before you can write a proxy queue. I'd suggest to google for networking tutorials, write some basic C programs with sockets, play around with `wireshark`, play around with `socat` etc. This will probably take you a few weeks. Once you are more comfortable with the basics, you can try to write a proxy yourself.

Comment: I got billed for $11,000 because my employer's AWS account got hacked. Thanks a ton for the information. I looked this up and I had one more question : `69756 437.047250 10.[my.phones.ip].151 255.255.255.255 UDP 82 57621 → 57621 Len=40` ...This port is accessed by spotify for P2P and I did not understand why

Comment: 255.255.255.255 is a broadcast address. There are many uses for this address (e.g. name resolution, local service announcements), and with the information you gave, it's impossible to say what Spotify is doing in this particular instance. Read up on broadcasts (both OSI level 2 and level 3) in the networking tutorials.

Comment: Found a link for chromecast debugging using chrome browser : https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging

Comment: Spotify prefetching happens using P2P when the player reaches the last 30s of a song, which are the requests shown in Wireshark.  http://www.csc.kth.se/~gkreitz/spotify-p2p10/